# Sort array based on the number of elements in the secondary array set as the value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3

I gave an array populated to look like this -

```
$array = array(
   0 => array(2,3,4),
   1 => array(2,3,7,6,8),
   -- and so on  
 );
```

Is there a shorthand in PHP/PHP5.x to accomplish sorting of such an array based on the number of elements in the value to each key of the primary array?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if (count($a) == count($b)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (count($a) < count($b)) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

Here's a better optimized version of that function (only calling `count()` twice):

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $numA = count($a);
    $numB = count($b)
    if ($numA == $numB) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($numA < $numB) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, awesome and thanks. Didn't know about this function, new stuff learnt :-)

Comment: @kuroineko -Agreed, "the comparison function must return an integer <, =, or > than 0" .